# How can I round a float number to a nearest largest int number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

For example I have 1.242533222, I want to round it to 2.
In other words, I want to round a float number to a nearest largest integer number.
How to do that in Python 3?

Comment: you better add the python tag to the question!

Comment: @Afghanistan: SO is a collaborative site, next time you can add required tags to the question yourself using `edit` button - just as I did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to round a float number to a nearest largest integer number. For example 1.232323 to 2, 5.12521369 to 6, 7.12532656 to 8

You are looking for the [ceiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of a number, which Python provides via the [`math.ceil()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/math.html#math.ceil) function:

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.5 (default, Jul 30 2013, 20:11:30)
[GCC 4.8.1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(1.232323)
2
>>> math.ceil(5.12521369)
6
>>> math.ceil(7.12532656)
8
```

Comment: Ok i got you, thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Many languages have a Math library. Apparently in Python, it looks like this:

```
math.ceil(1.24533222).
```

see http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

if you want this in the int data type, do this:

```
int(math.ceil(1.24533222))
```

Comment: you misunderstand my question

Comment: @user3358812: You should clarify and add details to your question then

Comment: Not sure what you want then. Is the issue the data type of the result?

Comment: I want to round a float number to a nearest largest integer number. For example (1.232323 to 2),        (5.12521369 to 6),      (7.12532656 to 8)

Comment: It seems that the issue is data type. I have revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note in Python 3 [`math.ceil()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/math.html) returns an int, though your suggestion is useful for Python 2.

Comment: Good catch, I was on the 2.7 docs. That said, the original answer should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try using float if you want float!

```
float(math.ceil(5.12521369))
```

otherwise,

```
math.ceil(5.12521369)
```

Comment: Python doesn't have typecasting; `float` simply constructs a new object using an existing object.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import math:

```
def ceil(num):
    floor = int(num)
    if floor != num:
        return floor + 1
    return floor
```